# Switching to innoDB (mysql)

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I'm running a classfieds website which has a records around 300K, it was on MyISAM engine but site at times will go high load and it will make server crashed. So my IT tech decided to switch to innoDB, since site is switched to innoDB it is very slow and taking alot of CPU 300%.

My IT tech said because changes are made recently he believes it is rebuilding indexes that's why site is slow and taking alot of cpu. Just want to know how true it is?

Comment: belongs on http://serverfault.com
Q&A for system administrators and desktop support professionals

Comment: Or to: [http://dba.stackexchange.com/](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: True: I forget there's DBA site

Answer (score 2):

We can't tell without looking at the server, but it is possible. Other things that could be causing this is not enough memory assigned to InnoDB. People often forget to tweak default values in `my.cnf` file, which results in poor performance and a lot of disk I/O